# Design patterns em projetos Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, design-pattern

Nos ultimos 12 meses eu tenho trabalhado e estudado para aprender a criar APIs REST com o Spring boot, antes disso eu trabalhava com programação php MVC para criar sistemas web e agora nessa minha "migração" para Java usando Spring eu estou tendo duvida/dificuldade para entender se o Spring usa algum tipo de design pattern e qual seria ?

Geralmente crio classes que seguem a seguinte ordem:
RestController -> Service -> Repository e classes Domain e DTO para as entidades e conversão/formatação das entidades

Essa estrutura que estou usando pode ser considerada um padrão de design ? Qual seria ?

Acho que por eu ser auto didata eu continuo com essa duvida simples em relação ao pessoal mais javeiro!

Comment: Acho que ele se refere à parte do backend. Tem cara de ser modelo anêmico.

Comment: Sim, é a parte de back. Dando uma pesquisada encontrei um design chamado Facade, que pelo que entendi serve para unir vários objetos em um, fazendo um agrupamento e formando um novo objeto. Existe mais algum que é bastante utilizado em ambiente de back-end ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Essa estrutura que estou usando pode ser considerada um padrão de design ? Qual seria ?

Sim. Este padrão que está usando é bem próximo ao que chamam de [Transaction Script Pattern](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1398617).

É uma dúvida simples, mas a grande maioria dos profissionais não está ciente que este é um modelo existente e que até tem um nome ou, muitas vezes, nem sabe que [existem outras maneiras de organizar a aplicação](http://lorenzo-dee.blogspot.com/2014/06/quantifying-domain-model-vs-transaction-script.html).

Acredito que sua popularidade deve-se ao fato de ser [simples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16400738/2387977) de entender, aplicar e de ser um modelo que atende bem a maioria das aplicações, como [explicado por Fowler](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1398617):

> The glory of Transaction Script is its simplicity. Organizing logic this way is natural for applications with only a small amount of logic, and it involves very little overhead either in performance or in understanding.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, eu estava bem perdido sobre esse assunto e agora tenho um norte para estudar sobre esse padrão!

Comment: @user2831852 bons estudos. Embora tenha recebido alguns negativos, eu pessoalmente entendo que sua dúvida seja bem válida.